# Mongoose unique field handling

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a question for which I haven't found an answer in Google. It is about mongoose and saving an object with unique field.

For example, I have a model, let's call it Product. It should have a unique numeric id, let's say the name of the field will be productId. Right now I just generate random 16 digits:

```
var id = (Math.random()+' ').substring(2,10)+(Math.random()+' ').substring(2,10);
```

And then just creating Product:

```
var product = { productId: id }
Product.create(product, (err, product) => { rest goes here });
```

And so the actual question is: how can I check is the Product with this id already exist, and if it does by any chance, regenerate id as many times as needed until there'll by no Product with this productId, and only then create it.

In Schema I define productId to be unique field. I guess I have to do something with error handling, but I just can't find what exactly.

Comment: You could try `Product.find({productId:id})` and if it returns a result, it already exists

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I think too. But how to make in a... idk, a loop? Like ii it’s exist, then I need to regenerate ID and try again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDb create a unique object id for you by default even if you don't bother try to create a id. Since you also create a random ID for a product my recommendation is that you don't need to worry about creating a unique id.

but if you really insist on creating a unique id, using mongoose if you add unique attribute, at a point if someone tries to add an id that is not unique, it will automatically throw an error. So you don't need to worry about validating it mongoose handles it by default.

**as for your problem of finding a user whether a user already exists**

if exists trying again the recreation of the unique id has this problem of unknown time of iterations it would run at a worst case.
so considering that what happens if a worst case let's say if it iterates over 100 times..
(mathematically speaking - probability wise this 100 times iteration value may not be true but as for an example).

So if you want to take that chance and go ahead anyways, you can do it like this

```
function genId(){
  return (Math.random()+' ').substring(2,10)+(Math.random()+' ').substring(2,10);
}


recreateOrInsert(genId());

function recreateOrInsert(id){
   Product.find({productId:id},(err,data)=>{
      if(err)throw err;
      if(data.length==0){ //remember here data comes as an array
         var product = { productId: id };
         Product.create(product, (err, product) => { rest goes here });
      }else{
         recreateOrInsert(genId());
      }
    });
}
```

In here you will create a loop which's iteration count is unknown.. so you really need to watch out for it.. but as for your question this is the way

Comment: Thank you! I’ll definitely gonna try that.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry :( so I generate id before Product.find(), throwing error if it's error, then I'm checking (by your code) if there's any data, if not... generate again id? why? and if there is data, where is a line of code that regenerate id to try again?

Comment: oops sorry my bad.. I completely missed it anyways now its ok try it again ..  :)

Comment: Thank you A LOT! That works!! Exactly as I wanted it!

Comment: my pleasure  :) . if you are pleased consider voting as well : )